# how to design all time running services for generating notifications?

Tags: android, service

I want to start a service for my app that will run all the time (even when the app is not running )
and should generate notifications after meeting some database values !!!
How to implement this ??
eg : for a class time table app : the app should generate notifications for next class after getting next class details from the database ..

Comment: well for one there is no such thing as a service that will "run all the time" the OS can kill the service anytime it needs resources

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Android Service to do this job, use sticky_service to overcome the issue of OS killing it on low memory. 
Also make sure you start your service on device reboot by registering to BOOT_COMPLETED receiver.